# Implementing typeahead.js CSS issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having a problem using the typeahead.js, a new plugin from twitter you can view an example of how this plugin is supposed to look: http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/

You can see my implementation here: http://mypcisbroke.co.uk/problem/

My issues

- The textbox should change to white on focus (this worked prior to installation of plugin)
- Suggestions which autocomplete in textbox should be in a lighter colour

Here is my site css

```
.navbar .top-search form { margin: 0 10px 0 0; padding-top: 5px; position: relative; }
.navbar .top-search input, .navbar .top-search button { -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; transition: all 200ms ease-in-out; }
.navbar .top-search input { padding: 2px 24px 2px 10px; border: none; margin: 0; width: 150px; background: #999; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; moz-border-radius: 20px; -ms-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; }
.navbar .top-search input:focus { background: #f5f5f5; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -ms-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }
.navbar .top-search button { opacity: .6; position: absolute; right: 7px; top: 9px; padding: 0; margin: 0; line-height: 12px; background: none; border: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -ms-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }
.navbar .top-search input:focus + button { opacity: 1 }
```

This is the styling of typeahead

```
.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On the `typeahead.css` file, on line 13 you have a line of code that reads this

```
background-color: transparent !important;
```

This is necessary, for this exact reason. It is creating a background-color of `transparent` for everything in `.tt-query` (but I'm not sure where this is located, because nothing has a class of `tt-query` in your html). Your `:focus` styles are fine. If you remove `!important`, then your code should function fine.

As an alternative, you could use the method that dark suggested, and add `!important` to the focus styles. This works, but I only use this for bug fixing and production. Rarely do I use this on a deployed site

Comment: You are right aswell, this also worked but also hides the suggestions because it takes priority. The plugin creates a second textbox for suggestions which it places dirrectly ontop of the original. The problem is the focust is never on .tt-hint its on the original textbox...

Comment: Can you add your html to the original question?

Comment: I can only see it when I view the dom with firebug or chrome developer tools. You can see what I mean by going here: http://mypcisbroke.co.uk/problem/example2.html, I've removed the styling

Comment: Yes the suggestion box works, my problem now is that it doesnt show the rest of the work as it auto fills. Check out the example: http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/ As you type the first word is displayed in the textbox is a lighter color

Comment: Oh I see it now. That is `placeholder`. And even by viewing their source I can't find any `placeholder` configurations

Comment: I understood it. I don't know how to accomplish that. Can you either add more code to your question or make a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your comment, I think its actual input value no? If you look at http://mypcisbroke.co.uk/problem/example2.html you can see the plugin clones the original textbox (with the same background) which it places under the original textbox, then sets the makes the original textbox transparent. However because the cloned textbox is never is focus the background never changes. Can I change the background of tt-hint when focus is on tt-query I;m thinking?

Comment: Try changing `.navbar .top-search input:focus` to `.navbar .tt-ltr input:focus, .navbar .tt-ltr input:nth-of-type(2):focus input:first-child`

Comment: Notice I changed `.top-search` to `.tt-ltr`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24995/discussion-between-cody-guldner-and-amof)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? My problem is similar: the text and the suggestion text for some reason are the same color (black). I need the suggestion text to be gray (like in the examples in the typeahead site). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the `!important` rule on `.navbar .top-search input` and you'll get the white on focus. There is obviously a specificity conflict somewhere ..

   Add it like this:

   ```
   .navbar .top-search input:focus {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5 !important;
   box-shadow: none;
   }
   ```
2. To change the suggestions font-color just edit your `.tt-suggestion p` selector in your `typeaheadstyling.css` file on line `58`

Comment: `!important` should be used very seldomly

Comment: Almost there, after adding important it hides the suggestions? The plug seems to create a transparent textbox on top of each other thats why the focus is technically still on the other right?

Comment: Look at my answer, I think it will solve the problem of the transparent suggestions

Comment: @PerfectDark see my latest comment to cody with the screenshot, thanks